# No signal to external monitor: Mac with basic M1

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport, apple-silicon

Today I bought a new external monitor ([Samsung Odyssey G3](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/gaming/27--odyssey-g3-monitor-lf27g35tfwnxza/)) to use alongside my Mac with basic M1 running macOS Monterey 12.5.

The connection cable type is HDMI to USB-C. However, when I bought the monitor, there was a Display Port cable too.

When I connected the external display to my Mac, it said **no signal** and then nothing happened.

I figured out that since it is a Mac M1, it's useless to reset SMC or something else. Then I tried unplugging everything and plugging again and/or restarting the computer.

Some folks suggested to check the display settings. When I go there, there is no such thing as "Detect display". Then I downloaded some app from App Store and it did not work as well.

Is there any solution/suggestion to follow and fix this problem?

What I have in my mind is to try the Display Port cable and/or downgrade to Big Sur, but before I downgrade if possible I want to fix this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you tried the Display Port cable with Monterey? Have you tried a different HDMI-to-USB-C cable?

Comment: You need a USB-C to HDMI adaptor, not HDMI to USB-C. These cables are not bi-directional.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for suggestion. Indeed, these cables are not bi-directional. I bought USB-C to HDMI and it works now.